# hydra composition for ML models

Tags: fb-hydra

I have some configurations for ML components as follows:

```
ml/encoder.yaml

hidden_layers_sizes: [2000, 1000, 300]
z_dim: 50

ml/decoder.yaml

hidden_layers_sizes: [300, 1000, 2000]
z_dim: 50
```

Now I have another configuration file as `models/vae.yaml` which I want to define as having these encoder and decoder configurations.

So the whole thing is structured as:

```
- conf
  - ml
    - encoder.yaml
    - decoder.yaml
  - models
    - vae.yaml
```

How should I define in `vae.yaml`so that the configuration of the encoders and decoders can be passed down to the underlying object (and be overridden if possible by the command line)?

I tried something like:

```
# @package _global_

defaults:
  - override /ml/encoder: encoder
  - override /ml/decoder: decoder
```

However, this results in  `Could not override 'ml/encoder'. No match in the defaults list.`

Comment: The [`override`](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/defaults_list/#introduction) keyword is used to update a previous default setting. I don't think you need to use `override` in this situation because you have not previously selected options for `/ml/encode` or `/ml/decoder`. Could you please try removing the `override` keyword from your file `vae.yaml`?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working as:

```
defaults:
 - encoder: vae_encoder
 - decoder: vae_decoder
```

I changed the config to look as:

```
- conf
  - models
    - encoder
      - encoder.yaml
    - decoder
      - decoder.yaml
    - vae.yaml
```